# Missing $ inserted in a table for superscript

Tags: tables, superscripts

I get the error message of `missing $ inserted` in my table.

```
\toprule
 ABS & \ 14,573.300^a & 3 & 4,857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
\midrule
```

I had tried:

```
\toprule
 ABS & \[14,573.300^a\] & 3 & 4,857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
\midrule
```

Basically, i need put the figure below with subscript in my table

[image]

Comment: The `^`  particle should only ever be used in math mode. For the problem at hand, replace `^a` with `\textsuperscript{a}` -- unless you're really trying to display "14573 to the a'th power"...

Comment: By the way, what is `a` supposed to denote? Is it a footnote marker? Please advise.

Comment: @Mico Yes, it will be a footnote marker for `a`

Comment: Please provide complete small document not just code fragment ... see, if maybe use of the `threeparttable` can help you (it define `\tnote` for such purposes).

Comment: why not use `\footnotemark` ? (or as Zarko just suggested a table notes macro?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In TeX and LaTeX, the `^` symbol should only ever be used in math mode, to denote exponentiation. However, you're not really trying to typeset "14,573.000 to the *a*'th power", right?

- The brute-force solution would be to input `14,573.300\textsuperscript{a}`. However, this approach doesn't exploit knowledge that `a` is supposed to be a footnote marker.
- A much better solution is to load the `threepartable` package and to use its `\tnote` macro to typeset the footnote markers; the markers can be letters, numbers, symbols, or what-have-you. And, use a `tablenotes` environment *after* the end of the `tabular` environment to typeset the footnote material itself.

  A serious advantage of the latter approach is that the machinery of the `threeparttable` will automatically set the width of the `tablenotes` environment to that of the associated `tabular` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\renewcommand{\TPTtagStyle}{\itshape} % optional
\usepackage{lipsum} % for filler text
\begin{document}

%% Approach 1: The brute-force method
\begin{table}[ht!]
\caption{A table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
 ABS & \ 14,573.300\textsuperscript{a} & 3 & 4,857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

%% Approach 2: The intelligent method
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{threeparttable}
\caption{Another table}
\begin{tabular}{@{} *{6}{c} @{}}
\toprule
 ABS & \ 14,573.300\tnote{a} & 3 & 4,857.767 & 40.297 & .000 \\
\midrule
\end{tabular}

\footnotesize 
\begin{tablenotes}
\item[a]\lipsum*[2] % the footnote itself 
\end{tablenotes}

\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: thanks. Why `\item[a]\lipsum[testing]` the footnote keep repeat it 2 times, the outcome is `testingtesting`. How to make it to only appear `testing`?

Comment: and it said `missing numbers, treated as zero`

Comment: I found. `\item[a] My Note.`. Between what is `\lipsum` used for? I googled, cannot understand fully

Comment: @aan - The command `\lipsum` is there to generate gibberish filler text. Its argument is optional and must be either a single integer or a range of integers, say, `\lipsum[2]` (see above) or `\lipsum[1-20]`. The former command prints out a single paragraph of filler text, whereas the latter outputs 20 [!] consecutive paragraphs of filler text. You can read more about the `lipsum` package [online](https://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum). `\lipsum[testing]` is a syntax error. To print out just the word "testing" after the footnote marker, write `\item[a]testing`.